# Reverse proxy for dynamic container

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a `docker-compose` setup. Various containers communicate with each other. Further, the setup should allow to run containers dynamically. Now, I am trying to expose some through a nginx reverse proxy server. This works fine for all containers with known hosts in advance. However, I would like to dynamically proxy all containers with the prefix `containeraaa-` as shown below.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  container-api:
    build: ./api
  containerzzz
    build: ./zzz

  # the following can change dynamically:

  containeraaa-x:
    image: nginx:alpine
  volumes:
    - ./x:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
  containeraaa-y:
    image: nginx:alpine
  volumes:
    - ./y:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
  containeraaa-z:
    image: nginx:alpine
  volumes:
    - ./z:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro

  # reverse-proxy:

  reverse-proxy:
    ports:
        - 80:80
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./reverse-proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

**nginx.conf**:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location ~ ^/aaa/(?<fwd_path>.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://containeraaa-$fwd_path; # error
        }

        location /aaa {
            proxy_pass http://container-api:8080/api/; # resolves correctly
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://containerzzz/; # resolves correctly
        }
    }
[…]
```

Even though `http://containeraaa-x` can be accessed from inside the reverse-proxy container; requesting `/aaa/x` leads to an ERROR:

```
no resolver defined to resolve containeraaa-x.
```

If I add

```
resolver 127.0.0.11
```

it tries to access `/usr/share/nginx/html/aaa/x`.

What would be the correct approach to resolve `/aaa/x` to `http://containeraaa-x` or is this simply not possible? Why and how exactly does `http://containerzzz/` work but `http://containeraaa-*` not?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `^/aaa/(?<fwd_path>(.*))$`?

Comment: For me it doesn't make a difference… Does it for you?

Answer (score -1):

You should use [traefik](https://traefik.io/) which is "the cloud native edge router".
To use it launch a traefik container within your docker-compose setup and add labels to containers you want to expose through traefik.

To launch the traefik container, you should do something like this:

```
traefik:
  image: traefik
  command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --docker.domain=basedomain.com
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 8080
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And put a service behind the reverse proxy:

```
the_app:
  depends_on:
    - traefik
  ports:
    - 80
  labels:
    - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:the_app.domain
    - traefik.port=80
```

And you're done exposing your services.

Comment: Even though this might be an alternative, I think this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: true but to me it's a lot easier and a lot better, also you don't do tricks with container names prefix, you use docker labels. Still , you're right, it's not the answer to your question ;)